# flutter code changes not happening in windows app and chrome

Tags: flutter

I am beginner starting to learn flutter, my pc doesn't have enough resources top run a android emulator (low drive space I guess). So I am using chrome and windows application option in visual code. But it doesn't show any change. what am I missing?

windows app is supposed to show green background and red header

[image]

Comment: do you get the same error while running on chrome?

Comment: Yes. Chrome, windows app, emulator, edge. Same error. Some issue with code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

the changes aren't made because your application crashed.
you should run `flutter clean` to solve the issue.

Comment: tried that. didnt work.

Comment: does your application crashes everytime?

Comment: it doesn't crash. It just doesn't show results. Clicking on the plus sign causes the number to change .

Comment: if it is not crashing and number is updating then your is working correctly. you have to save your file and then hot reload to show changes on your app

Comment: according to the picture you have posted your app is crashing. try googling  `link fatal error lnk1168 flutter windows`

Comment: i googled it. I am not recieveing any errors. Issue is there is no output

Comment: if you are not recivieng any error then you should be able to hot reload the app by typing `r` in the terminal, you have to hot reload to show changes in your app

Answer (score 0):

I got to work, I had two files- main.dart and my_app.dart. Main was blank.I was running the other file which contained the actual code. I deleted main.dart and renamed my_app file as main.dart. That solved the problem. I am now getting output as expected